# Exclude rows from a SQL query based on number of rows an ID is present in

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I was extracting some data earlier and found my results too numerous to be of any use (over 4 million rows returned). I found the culprit to be a large handful of IDs that have several thousand records apiece.

Heres the structure of the data. I have two tables. tbl1 has a single record of every 'ATID' (an ATID being a scale id, basically). Each ATID is in essence its own table, though - it has a record for every item on the scale. tbl2 enumerates those items - it has a row for every scale item per ATID. So it has anywhere from 1 to 500,000 rows for each ATID (I know, pretty f'ing excessive).

I'd like to exclude the ATIDs which have over 100 rows. FYI this is a database I have read-only access to.

Here's my original query:

```
SELECT tbl1.ATID, tbl1.ATDesc, tbl2.AValue, tbl2.ADesc, tbl2.APosNeg
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON (tb1.ATID = tbl2.ATID);
```

Here's the query I used to get a list of ATIDs and record counts in tbl2 per ATID:

```
select ATID, count(*) as row_count
from tbl2
group by ATID
order by row_count desc;
```

For my end product I'd like to return only ATIDs with fewer than 100 rows in tbl2. However, if I even try to add a WHERE clause to the second query using the row_count variable, it fails. So I have no idea how to even approach combining the two queries and getting the WHERE clause in.

The only alternative I have is to exclude ATIDs specifically when I know they have too many records, but there are too many to exclude (ie, using WHERE NOT ATID = 1016 AND NOT ATID = 554 AND NOT .... etc)

Comment: Do you know how to do a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already done it, you just need to put your two queries together:

```
SELECT tbl1.ATID, tbl1.ATDesc, tbl2.AValue, tbl2.ADesc, tbl2.APosNeg
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON (tb1.ATID = tbl2.ATID)
WHERE tbl1.ATID NOT IN (
  select ATID
  from tbl2
  group by ATID
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it using

`Count() Over()` window aggregate will `count` the number of records for each `ATID` in `tbl2` table. Then count the can be used to filter the `ATID` in `Join` condition

```
SELECT tbl1.ATID,
       tbl1.ATDesc,
       tbl2.AValue,
       tbl2.ADesc,
       tbl2.APosNeg
FROM   tbl1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Count(1)OVER(partition BY ATID) AS cnt,*
                        FROM   tbl2) tbl2
                    ON tb1.ATID = tbl2.ATID
                       AND tbl2.cnt <= 100;
```

**Note :** If you dont want all the `ATID's` from `tabl1` then move the `tbl2.cnt <= 100` condition to `Where` clause so you will get the count of `ATID's` whose count is less than `100` in `tbl2`

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server, use a CTE (faster than a sub-query). Also, unnecessary brackets in your query

```
with RowCo as
(
select ATID, count(*) as row_count
from tbl2
group by ATID
having row_count <= 100
)

SELECT tbl1.ATID, tbl1.ATDesc, tbl2.AValue, tbl2.ADesc, tbl2.APosNeg
FROM tbl1 
inner join RowCo
    on RowCo.ATID = tbl1.ATID
LEFT JOIN tbl2 
    ON tb1.ATID = tbl2.ATID
```

Comment: Thanks - what makes a CTE faster than a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

For the second query, the filters related to aggregate functions goes on a HAVING section

```
select ATID, count(*) as row_count
from tbl2
group by ATID
order by row_count desc;
having count(*) < 100
```

And for the first query you can simply use a subquery

```
SELECT tbl1.ATID, tbl1.ATDesc, tbl2.AValue, tbl2.ADesc, tbl2.APosNeg
FROM tbl1 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON (tb1.ATID = tbl2.ATID)
WHERE tbl1.ATID in (select ATID
                    from tbl2
                    group by ATID
                    having count(*) < 100)
```